# "Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end" error when listing files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to write a function in Google Apps Script to list all files in my Google Drive folders.

The code below returns:

> Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.`

while looping through files. It works on most folders, until it fails with the exception. Any ideas on what causes this to bomb out?

```
function listAllFilesInFolder() {
  var foldername = 'My Drive';
  var filenames = 'filenames_' + foldername;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var folder = folders.next();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(filenames);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var file;
  var data = [];
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    data.push([
      file.getName()
    ]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: I think  `var folder = folders.next();` this line causes error,  you should check with `hasNext` first.

Comment: Your code looks OK. Are you sure this is really the code you are running, eg you don't have a second call to `files.next()` somewhere? Try adding `!!` to `files.hasNext()` to give `!!files.hasNext()`. Also you should log `files` to see if there is anything unusual about it prior to the exception (or catch the exception and log it there)

Comment: My thought is OP is manually changing `foldername` and executing this standalone script. Note that "My Drive" is not actually the name - you probably wanted [`DriveApp.getRootFolder()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getRootFolder()) If that's the case, please re-edit the title to something like "Using getFoldersByName to access 'My Drive' folder has no results"

Comment: I confirm, my drive is not a folder name, it's the root folder. Try your code with a "real" folder name.