# Google drive script exception "Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

H, I have created a script where I check the destination folder on google drive if the file exist I get the id of the file otherwise I create file there and get the ID, the issue I am facing is w it work perfectly sometime, but sometime I am getting the exception "Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end." I can confirm that the file is on the destination folder but still this exception occurs. I have used sleep function if there is any delay in creation of file. I also have checked few issue shared by others as well.
["Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end" error when listing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443719/cannot-retrieve-the-next-object-iterator-has-reached-the-end-error-when-listi)

```
   //Copy File to Destination
function CopyFileNew(file,dest,source,filename){

  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(dest);
  var filecheck  = destination.getFilesByName(filename);

  if(!filecheck.hasNext()){
    destination.addFile(file);//file is undefined

    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    var newfile=destination.getFilesByName(filename);
    if(newfile.hasNext()){
      Utilities.sleep(2000);
      return "https://drive.google.com/open?id="+newfile.next().getId(); // HERE I GET THE ERROR
    }
  }
  else{
    return "https://drive.google.com/open?id="+filecheck.next().getId(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `file` is undefined

Comment: File was globally defined, now it is part of the parameter

Comment: My guess is that 2 seconds is not nearly enough time.  I'd probably want to wait at least 15 or 20 seconds.

Comment: What is `file`? How are you creating it? I've tested this with `file = DriveApp.getFileById("[spreadsheet-id]")` as well as `file = DriveApp.createFile("filename", "content");` and both work with no error. Is the file particularly large? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: File can be any file type, in this case is a pdf file. and file size is less 1 MB. but the only thing different here is the destination folder is shared folder.

Comment: No idea why this error occurs, even I have increased the sleep time to 10 seconds

Comment: `the only thing different here is the destination folder is shared folder` do you mean a folder shared with someone, or a shared drive?

Comment: folder is shared from someone else google drive.

Comment: I can't replicate this at all. The only thing I can imagine is that `filename` != `file.getName()`. Can you confirm this?